# Copy values from existing CSV column and add to new column with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, system-administration

I have a CSV with 4 Columns. I am trying to copy values from the costs column to the corpcosts columns based on values from the department number column. Basically, any cost with department number starting with 8* to be moved or copied to the corpcost column.

For reference:

Original:

| Employee ID | OwnerEmail | DepartmentNumber | Costs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fg345 | test@mail.com | 8894 | 4654.45 |
| 78f54 | test2@mail.co | 3453 | 4994.15 |

Expectation:

| Employee ID | OwnerEmail | DepartmentNumber | Costs | CorpCosts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fg345 | test@mail.com | 8894 | 4654.45 | 4654.45 |
| 78f54 | test2@mail.co | 3453 | 4994.15 |  |

I have tried using a foreach loop, but I must admit I am fairly new to PowerShell and learning as I go. The code I have tried thus far is as follows:

```
$corpcosts= foreach($corpcost in $CSVImport.corpcosts){
        if($CSVImport.DepartmentNumber -eq "8*"){
            $CSVImport.DepartmentNumber + $CSVImport.Costs 
        }
    }
           
$CSVImport|Select-Object *, @{N= 'CorpCosts'; E={$corpcosts[$_.CorpCosts]}} |Export-Csv "$Env:temp/$OutputFile" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with just one [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2), for the comparison you could either use [`.StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-7.0) or a [Matching Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) of your choice (either `-like '8*'` or `-match '^8'`), not that [equality operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#equality-operators) are not aware of [wildcard characters (`*`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3).

```
Import-Csv path\to\source.csv |
    Select-Object *, @{N='CorpCosts';E={ if($_.DepartmentNumber.StartsWith('8')) { $_.Costs } }} |
    Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

The Expression only needs a few changes to add an if statement to check for departments starting with the number 8, and if true, fill with the Costs column into the new CorpCosts column.

```
$CSVImport = Import-Csv Costs.csv
$CSVImport|Select-Object *, @{N= 'CorpCosts'; E={if($_.DepartmentNumber -like '8*'){$_.Costs}}} | Export-Csv "$Env:temp/$OutputFile" -NoTypeInformation
```